# Connection Error: Unable to create selectable TCP socket (1121 >= 1024)

Tags: php, sockets, tcp

Thanks in advance.
I have created php-imap class for retrieving email from email client. It worked fine for last 3 months. Now it showing the following error "Connection Error: Unable to create selectable TCP socket (1121 >= 1024)". 
I goggled it and find some solutions like "FD_SETSIZE,this is an outdated code of the c-client, this uses the select() method instead of the poll() method". May be its the problem, if this is the problem why this works for last three month.
Anyone know about this error.

Comment: @tlenss, here i used php for imap

Comment: My bad! But this might be related to the c-library PHP uses. http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=548857